# Self-employed in two jurisdictions simultaneously

Tags: ireland, pension

I am a UK resident and have paid self-employed contributions simultaneously in the UK and Ireland as I had a separate business in both jurisdictions for over 25 years in each. I am of pension age and receive my UK pension, but Ireland has refused me a pension despite acknowledging my contributions. Can that be correct?

Comment: For clarity, are you referring to the state pension? What reason(s) did the Irish authorities give for refusing? https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/social-welfare/social-welfare-payments/older-and-retired-people/state-pension-contributory/#:~:text=To%20qualify%20for%20a%20State%20Pension%20(Contributory)%20you%20must%20be,called%20full%2Drate%20PRSI%20contributions

Comment: I am referring to government pensions.

Comment: @Traveller, Although I'm fairly certain you can see the deleted post, I'm posting a quote of the comment response to your query here for all others, *quote Kieran Connolly* - "The Irish Government stated that I was not entitled because I had made simultaneous contributions in the UK where I live and from where I get my State Pension."

Comment: What is your citizenship? Have you ever lived in Ireland? Were your contributions compulsory or voluntary? If you have never been resident in Ireland, did you get professional financial advice before making contributions?